# How to use Social Network Login or oAuth?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I am planning to build a simple login system where user can SignUp with both `Faceboook` and `Normal SignUp`. I know how to get name,email and other things from `Facebook` after successful login. I can't figure out how the `Social Network` login system works.

Here's my `user` table structure.

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) NOT NULL
```

What should i do after successful facebook login?

1) Should i save the user email in my database ?

2) What should be the user password then?

3) How can i recognise the same user on next login?

Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 3):

the following link will be very helpful for you. it has all the steps from scratch on how to authenticate users using facebook.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect--net-12302

Also you can refer to facebook developers guide for code examples

https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: That was a helpful link, but Gautam i need answers for those questions.

Comment: u won have to use password then, the login will be besed on facebook credentials, the api key which u get from facebook. so u will have to store those keys in database.you can store email and other info for any other use. The user will be recognized besed on the key..the key will be unique for every user.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use multi-provider you can use this framework : http://www.opauth.org.

Or you can go to each of social media platform's developer page for individually.

Note : Facebook keep changing its privacy policy that could impact its functionality in future.